# How to translate sql comparing pair of columns to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using sql executor to bring latest relevant banner titles with appversions <= of requested version
My idea was to group by articul, get max supported appversion and return all rows appropriate to those pairs (articul, max version)
Couldn't write a LINQ for it, so did it using sql executor by joining the table with itself.
Would be very grateful for help to rewrite it back to LINQ

```
var response_banners = await _sqlExecutor.Clone()
                .With(@$"select a.* from [dbo].[BannerData] as a join (")
                .With(@$"select articul, max(AppVersionAndroid) as appversion")
                .With(@$" from [dbo].[BannerData]")
                .With(@$" where AppVersionAndroid is not null and isenabled=1 and AppVersionAndroid<=").InPar(request.AppVersion)
                .With(@$" group by articul) as t on t.articul = a.articul and t.appversion = a.AppVersionAndroid order by sortindex")
                .ExecuteReaderAsync(r => new BannerDataDTO()
                {
                    Articul = r.ToString("Articul"),
                    Description = r.ToString("Description"),
                    ...

                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

example of data in table:

```
Id  Articul Title   AppVersionAndroid
1   AnimationBanner title1  2.0
2   test2   title2  1.5
3   AnimationBanner title3  1.1
4   NewAppVersionBanner title4  1.1
7   PaperPropositionBanner  title5  1.1
11  PennyAccountBanner  title6  1.1
13  DeliveryFreeBanner  title7  1.1
```

Comment: Why you can't write LIQN for that? Which ORM do you use?

Comment: EF core
haven't got an idea of which linq would suit

Comment: Yesterday, i have answered the similar question [DistinctBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72787160/10646316)