# How to write correlated queries in entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, specifications

**I need to translate this query into EF Core**

```sql
SELECT * FROM Release AS r1
WHERE r1.Status = 'Complete' AND
r1.UpdateDate = (
  SELECT MAX(UpdateDate)
  FROm RELEASE AS r2
  WHERE r2.Platform = r1.Platform AND
  r2.Status = 'Complete'
);
```

And it was great to have an idea how to write the same query using the specification pattern. There are not so many examples on the Internet about this, and nothing at all about correlated queries

Comment: You don't use `r` in your sub query. Did you mean to use `r1` in the main query?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72787160/10646316) It has custom `DistinctBy` implementation. Do not mess with .NET 6 `DistinctBy` function.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yea, I mean r1

Answer (score 0):

Results may vary, but this is how I would do it. It's not terribly efficient, but it gets the job done;

```
var result = await Release
.Where(r1 => r1.Status == "Complete" && r1.UpdateDate == Release
    .OrderByDescending(r2 => r2.UpdateDate)
    .First(r2 => r2.Platform == r1.Platform && r2.Status == "Complete").UpdateDate)
.ToListAsync();
```