# C# - SQL to LINQ Convertion (Select latest record by ID)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm trying to convert this sql statement to LINQ

```sql
select tm.pr_title, tm.pr_number, tm.pr_req, tm.pr_req_owner, tm.pr_dept_req, ts.pr_hdr_name , 
        ts.pr_id_ctgy_date, ts.pr_hdr_step from tb_pr_mst_record tm
inner join tb_pr_dtl_record ts on tm.pr_number = ts.pr_number
where (ts.pr_number, ts.pr_id_ctgy_date) in (
        select ts.pr_number, max(ts.pr_id_ctgy_date)
        from tb_pr_dtl_record ts
        group by ts.pr_number
);
```

Here is my table with the complete data

```
PR Title    PR Number    PR Req   PR Req Owner   PR Dept Req   PR HDR Name  PR ID CTGY DATE  PR HDR Step
TL1         E1900        USR1     USR1           DEP1          ESX          12/1/2022        8
TL1         E1900        USR1     USR1           DEP1          ESX          12/5/2022        8
TL1         E1900        USR1     USR1           DEP1          ESX          12/6/2022        8
TL2         E1300        USR2     USR2           DEP4          EPX          12/1/2022        8
TL2         E1300        USR2     USR2           DEP4          EPX          12/4/2022        8
TL2         E1300        USR2     USR2           DEP4          EPX          12/5/2022        8
```

This is the result I get when executing the query

```
PR Title    PR Number    PR Req   PR Req Owner   PR Dept Req   PR HDR Name  PR ID CTGY DATE  PR HDR Step
TL1         E1900        USR1     USR1           DEP1          ESX          12/6/2022        8
TL2         E1237        USR2     USR2           DEP4          EPX          12/5/2022        8
```

I tried to transcribe in LINQ but I can't interpret the WHERE statement of the above SQL query

```cs
var listq = from tm in entddb.TB_PR_MST_RECORD
            join ts in entddb.TB_PR_DTL_RECORD on tm.PR_NUMBER equals ts.PR_NUMBER
            select new InvIndexModels { 
                            mPR_TITLE = tm.PR_TITLE, 
                            mPR_REQ = tm.PR_REQ, 
                            mPR_REQ_OWNER = tm.PR_REQ_OWNER, 
                            mPR_DEPT_REQ = tm.PR_DEPT_REQ, 
                            mPR_HDR_NAME = ts.PR_HDR_NAME, 
                            mPR_ID_CTGY_DATE = ts.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE, 
                            mPR_HDR_STEP = ts.PR_HDR_STEP 
                        };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq to Entities - SQL "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Declare a variable with **let** and put the sub-request you are going to use to check the presence of the data couple `(ts.pr_number, ts.pr_id_ctgy_date)`. Next, in the parent request's `where` clause you check if the couple is in the sub-request.

Comment: Which ORM do you use and which version?

Comment: @JimG. 
Thanks but not working for me because only using a list while I need to do another sub process inside the where

Comment: With EF Core 6 this query can be written via GroupBy, for lower versions it is needed another implementation. With `linq2db` we can  use Window Functions. So, which ORM do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I use EF Core 5

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF Core 5 and lower, you can do the following:

```cs
var dtlRecords = entddb.TB_PR_DTL_RECORD.AsQueryable();

var latest =
    from d in dtlRecords.Select(d => new { d.PR_NUMBER }).Distinct()
    from dtl in dtlRecords
        .Where(dtl => dtl.PR_NUMBER == d.PR_NUMBER)
        .OrderbyDescending(dtl => dtl.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE)
        .Take(1)
    select dtl;

var listq = 
    from tm in entddb.TB_PR_MST_RECORD
    join ts in latest on tm.PR_NUMBER equals ts.PR_NUMBER
    select new InvIndexModels 
    { 
        mPR_TITLE = tm.PR_TITLE, 
        mPR_REQ = tm.PR_REQ, 
        mPR_REQ_OWNER = tm.PR_REQ_OWNER, 
        mPR_DEPT_REQ = tm.PR_DEPT_REQ, 
        mPR_HDR_NAME = ts.PR_HDR_NAME, 
        mPR_ID_CTGY_DATE = ts.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE, 
        mPR_HDR_STEP = ts.PR_HDR_STEP 
    };
```

With EF Core 6 you can build `latest` via `GroupBy`:

```cs
var latest =
    from dtl in dtlRecords
    group dtl by dtl.PR_NUMBER into g
    select g.OrderbyDescending(x => x.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE).First();
```

If it is repetitive task, the same result you can achieve via my implementation of `DistinctBy` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72787160/10646316).

```cs
var latest = dtlRecords.DistinctBy(d => d.PR_NUMBER, d => d.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE);
```

Comment: Works!! but there is a detail, when executing this query in PLSQL if in max(ts.pr_id_ctgy_date) it returns the last field that it detects with date with its respective PR HDR Step
running this in linq skips this as it shows me the last record max(ts.pr_id_ctgy_date) even though it is null

Comment: I do not know nature your data, but simple tuning may help:  `var dtlRecords = entddb.TB_PR_DTL_RECORD.Where(dtl => dtl.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE != null);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll work, but I would do something like this:

```
var listq = from tm in entddb.TB_PR_MST_RECORD
            join ts in entddb.TB_PR_DTL_RECORD on tm.PR_NUMBER equals ts.PR_NUMBER

            let subreq = from ts2 in entddb.TB_PR_DTL_RECORD
                         group ts2 by ts2.PR_NUMBER into g
                         select new { PR_NUMBER = g.Key, PR_ID_CTGY_DATE = g.Max(d => d.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE) }
                        
            where subreq.Contains(ts.PR_NUMBER) && subreq.Contains(ts.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE)
            select new InvIndexModels { 
                         mPR_TITLE = tm.PR_TITLE, 
                         mPR_REQ = tm.PR_REQ, 
                         mPR_REQ_OWNER = tm.PR_REQ_OWNER, 
                         mPR_DEPT_REQ = tm.PR_DEPT_REQ, 
                         mPR_HDR_NAME = ts.PR_HDR_NAME, 
                         mPR_ID_CTGY_DATE = ts.PR_ID_CTGY_DATE, 
                         mPR_HDR_STEP = ts.PR_HDR_STEP 
                       };
```

Comment: Writing the where statement gives me an error like: IQueryable<<anonymous>> does not contain a definition for 'Contains'