# C# Writing dynamic query function using expression trees

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, dynamicquery

Im trying to write a query function. And with expression trees I am trying to get runtime input to query.

```cs
var query = context.Customers            
    .Join(context.Orders,
        customer => customer.CustomerId,
        order => order.CustomerId,
    (customer, order) => new
    {
        customer.ContactName,
        order.ShipCountry
    }).Where(customer => customer.ContactName.StartsWith("A"))
    .ToList();
```

I created a simple query. Then tried to functionalize it using expression trees:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object> GetContactNameandOrderDate(string prop_1, string prop_2, string prop_3, string text)
{

    NorthwindContext context = new();

    var customer = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer));    //customer  
    var order = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Order));          //order

    var customerCustomerId = Expression.PropertyOrField(customer, prop_1);        //customer.CustomerId
    var orderCustomerId = Expression.PropertyOrField(order, prop_1);              //order.CustomerId
    var customerContactName = Expression.PropertyOrField(customer, prop_2);       //customer.ContactName
    var orderShipCountry = Expression.PropertyOrField(order, prop_3);             //order.ShipCountry

    var textConstant = Expression.Constant(text);  //"A"



    Expression<Func<Customer, int>> lambda_1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, int>>(customerCustomerId, customer);  //customer => customer.CustomerId
    Expression<Func<Order, int>> lambda_2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Order, int>>(orderCustomerId, order);     //  order => order.CustomerId




    Expression startsWith = Expression.Call(                    //customer.ContactName.StartsWith("A"))
                                customerContactName,
                                typeof(String).GetMethod("StartsWith",
                                            new Type[] { typeof(String) }), textConstant );




    Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> lambda_3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(startsWith, customer); //customer => customer.ContactName.StartsWith("A"))

    


    var values = context.Customers.Join(context.Orders, lambda_1, lambda_2, (customer, order) => new { customerContactName, orderShipCountry }).Where(lambda_3).ToList();  //lambda_3 error
    return values;
}
```

Im getting error at the `Where(lambda_3)` that says:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<expression_trees.Entities.Customer, bool>>' to 'System.Func<<anonymous type: System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression customerContactName, System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression orderShipCountry>, bool>'

Im guessing I did something wrong writing `customer.ContactName.StartsWith("A"))` as expression. But I could not figure out what is wrong.

I am essentially trying to figure out if I can use expression trees effectively and dynamic with entity framework. Like getting database objects that has "/" at the beggining in runtime. Is my approach wrong? How can i use expression trees effectively with entity framework? I could not find many resource on this topic so any recommendation would be helpful.

Comment: There is problem with anonymous types while building Expression Tree. I can correct your query but what is the reason to build such simple thing? Maybe you are trying to build something more useful?

Comment: You could say that. I am researching expression trees to see how i can utilize them with entity framework core . I read that they can be used to create dynamic queries. But I am a bit confused about it. I also could not find real world usage examples so I was trying to create something myself to see where it goes.

Comment: With Expression Trees you can create any query dynamically. Problem with anonymous types. It is very difficult to create them dynamically (but possible). Usually in such extensions used real class.

Comment: I see. Do you recommend any resource about this topic or anything useful that I can use?

Comment: I'm self-taught, usually it was Stack Overflow. At the start if was decompiling code which generates C# compiler, like`Expression<Func<IQueryable<Customer, IQueryable<Result>>>> func = q => q.Join(...)...` Then I have found this useful extension [Readable Expressions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers) to visualise what I have built.

Comment: Also useful was to look into `Queryable` extensions implementation. They have clue how to build such queries.

Comment: Thank you. To have a better view on Expressions , may I ask in which area you used Expressions? 
Also this might be a dumb question but I am very new c#: I saw that if I write a complex query with more than one table , the query is anonymous type, but if I write using only one table  the query returns objects of that tables type. Is this the kind of problem you mentioned with anonymous types?

Comment: Well, `Join`, `SelectMany`, GroupJoin` connects two recordsets into new projection - changing result type (here usually. anonymous type is used). `GroupBy` - always changes result type. We can talk whole day about this. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: *may I ask in which area you used Expressions?* - Simplifying extension methods used in application - simple syntax but under hood, several joins or something else like in this [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72787160/10646316)
Also I'm developing [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) which generates a way better SQL than EF for about ten years.

Comment: *What you are trying to achieve?* : I just wanted to clarify what you meant by *Problem with anonymous types* above.
I checked your linq2db work. Thats very impressive. Do you recommend a newbie to try these libraries like yours or should I stick with EF for now?

Comment: EF Core is good for complex model and processes. ChangeTracker simplifies a lot of  things, but if you need really complex queries with Window Functions, temporal tables, fast inserting, `linq2db` beats this monster like a child. I do not suggest to drop EF at all, you can use `linq2db` as a helper via [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore).

Comment: An example of what you can do is in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49418695/2557128). It also shows how you can use an example anonymous object to get a type when you know the shape of the anonymous class you need. I would also recommend LINQPad which is a good tool for dumping compiler created `Expression` trees so that you can see how they are built by the compiler.

Comment: C# is a language of types. What is the return type from the call to `Join`? What is the parameter type to the `lambda_3` lambda `Expression`?

Comment: PS See [this code](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/DynamicClassFactory.cs) from the Dynamic LINQ project to get a partial idea of why creating your own anonymous type is difficult.